# "should I" or "I should" in wh-question

Tags: word-order, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Which of the sentences below is correct (plus explanation if possible)? If both of them are incorrect, in any way, please suggest me another way to say it.

> *Which version **I should** choose to work with?*

> *Which version **should I** choose to work with?*

Comment: The second one is correct since it contains subject-auxiliary inversion, which is normal in such interrogatives.

Comment: What research did you do? For example, did you look on the 'Net or in a decent grammar book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wh questions are always inverted unless the wh-item is the subject of the question.

So

> Which version should I choose to work with?

(*Which version* is governed by the preposition *with*: the subject *I* follows the auxiliary)

but

> Which version would be best for me?

(*Which version* is the subect of *would be*, and precedes the verb in the usual way).

Answer (score -1):

Number 2 is correct. Look at the following sentences to understand why:

I should choose one version.

Should I choose one version?

Which version do I choose?

Which version did you choose?

Which version should I choose?

Comment: Thank you so much! i hope have a great day <3

Comment: Yes, but you should mention the reason why, i.e. that this kind of interrogative requires subject-auxiliary inversion.

Comment: @BillJ My experience shows metalinguistic knowledge is of little use in language learning. It's an old method. All you need is s sentence pattern in your mind and then you can easily make a large number of correct sentences. I never think about parts of speech or grammatical lables such an auxiliary, etc when I'm writing or speaking and my speaking and writing are good enough without them. Nobody has time to think about such things when reading, writing or hearing things rapidly.

Comment: Metalingustics have nothing whatsoever to do with this. It's about grammar. You have failed to answer the OP's question which specifically asked for an explanation about which one of their examples was correct. Read the approved answer for the correct and appropriate reply to the OP's question.

Comment: @BillJ grammar is metalinguistic knowledge. Hypothetically, you might be able to explain all the grammatical rules in a certain language, but you may not be able to produce a single grammatically correct sentence in that language. Grammar is all about sentence patterns. When we aquire our mother tongues, we don't do so through someone explaining to us the rules of grammar. We hear a large number of sentences and our mind does the job for us.

Comment: No it isn't. You're still missing the point, which is that your answer did **not** deal with the OP's question. Note the OP's words "plus explanation if possible".

Comment: This ***is*** an answer to the OP's literal question, and these sentence examples can be construed as an indirect reason. Without a direct explanation it might not be a *good answer* -- as we'll see from the +/- votes -- but it is an answer, especially as the OP only asked parenthetically for an explanation "if possible".

Comment: The point is that an explanation is possible, so one would expect it to be provided (especially as it's such a simple one). A lack of explanation might imply that there is isn't one, or that there is one but the answerer can't be bothered to provide it. Further, the answer is not helpful since, contrary to what it says, the examples it provides are unlikely to help the OP to "understand why".